# Redis for Java Play 2.x?

Tags: playframework, redis, playframework-2.2

It looks as if Redis module is available for Play 1.x only:
http://www.playframework.com/modules/redis

What do I need to use Redis database with a Play 2.2 app?

Comment: For future references, there is a play-redis plugin implementing cache api for play 2.3 and further https://github.com/KarelCemus/play-redis

Answer (score 1):

It's supported, and as of a month ago, upgraded to support Play 2.2:

See here: https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/blob/master/redis/sample/project/Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "j"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
       "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.2.0",
       "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-cache" % "2.2.0"
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
    )
}
```

And here it says this is a plugin for use with Jedis (Java) and Sedis (Scala):
https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis

So you probably want to use Jedis.

Comment: Thank you!  When I tried to run the sample app that comes with the typesafe redis project, I got the following error:  [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-redis_2.10;2.0.4: not found

Comment: @mobileideafactory.com: The trick is to actually find a version that exists in the repository. Go here to find one: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/ (I got that link from http://abansnest.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/playmongoredis.html)

Comment: I'd highly recommend checking out the [Scalable chat application with Play Framework 2.x and WebSockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets-advanced). It uses Redis (pub/sub), and the Jedis java client. Link to the github repository - https://github.com/heroku-examples/play-websockets-chat-sample